# After Using keepass to login putty

Tags: putty, keepass

I'm a new one about keepass. now I can login putty via keepass. But I'm want keepass after login a time later then excute some special command in putty ,is it possible?

Comment: Need your help, wait online, thank you

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want to achieve?

For instance, if you want to SSH including Password and a special port use the
URL Overrides in Options->Integration and define an override like that:

```
cmd://"C:\Program Files (x86)\putty\putty_0.63.exe" -ssh -l {USERNAME} -pw {PASSWORD} -P {URL:PORT} {URL:HOST}
```

That's the way you can also use to call a batch file which does whatever you want.